# Return index of matched array not working - Javascript Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet and row #1 has dates in each cell going across

I want to return the column number whenever that column matches today's date. First header starts in cell B1.

I am using the following and I can get it to work, but when instead I do 'return i', it always returns '0'.

```
function getColumnIndex() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,lastColumn).getValues(); //create an array of data from row 1
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy")
    if (data[i] == dateToday) {break};
    {  
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I switch the last line 'return i' to 'return dateToday' the function will work and it will return the correct date so I know it's matching properly (and if I change row cells to other values it will return those values if it matches). I just can't get it to spit out the index number when I put 'return i'.

Comment: Is this a date format issue somehow, so your comparison isn't matching?  To test this, instead of "return i", could you try return "data[2]", for example, to see whether that format matches what you get when you do "return dateToday"?  Just an idea...  Also, I haven't done much coding recently - is there any chance that the value of i is lost (set to zero) after you break out of the FOR loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues / Explanation:

1. `var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,lastColumn).getValues();` returns a 2D array.

As a result, `data[i]` returns a 1D array which is actually referring to the row. To solve this issue, [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array to convert it to 1D:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,lastColumn).getDisplayValues().flat();
```

---

2. Your `if` condition is executed at the first iteration `i=0` because you put a semicolon `;` right after it. Also, `break` is not needed because nothing will be executed after the `return` statement:

**Replace**:

```
if (data[i] == dateToday) {break};
{  
  return i;
}
```

**with**

```
if (data[i] == dateToday) 
{  
  return i;
}
```

---

3. When you are working with date comparisons, you need to use `getDisplayValues()` to be sure that you are comparing the the displayed values
   and not the value of the date.

---

### Solution:

```
function getColumnIndex() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,lastColumn).getDisplayValues().flat(); //create an array of data from row 1
  
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy")    
    if (data[i] == dateToday) 
    {  
      return i;
      // return i+2; // if you want to get the column number instead.
    }
  }
}
```

**Keep in mind**, `i` refers to the position of the array. In JavaScript, the indexes in the arrays start from `0`. Also, your data starts from the second column. If you want your script to return the number of column, then change `return i` to `return i+2`.

Comment: Brilliant, I read something about it producing a 2D array but didn't know what to do with that info - and that's why I kept getting an index return of 0 whenever it matched - because the first row is 0 so it was giving the correct return index, I just didn't know what I was doing. Also thanks for the pointer on removing the semicolon and moving the break. I was researching for hours today how to do this on my own having no knowledge of GAS but it's funny how someone who knows what they're doing can look at it instantly and figure it out

Comment: 1.`break`   statement is unreachable. Once the `return` executes, `break` is useless. 2. You should mention why you used `getDisplayValues()`

Comment: @TheMaster true, my bad :)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function getColumnIndexForToday() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const shsc=2;
  const offset=0;//0 if you want the index from column B 1 if you want the index from ColumnA
  const data=sh.getRange(1,shsc,1,sh.getLastColumn()-shsc+1).getDisplayValues()[0];//assuming format is "MM/dd/yyyy"
  var dObj={};
  data.forEach(function(h,i){dObj[h]=i+offset;});//You really can just do this once and then use it repeatedly
  var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy")
  return dObj[Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy")];
}
```